# Broken if/else statement

Tags: powershell

This script currently uses an `if...else` to ensure users enter a proper naming convention. The script executes just fine if they enter the proper convention. If they don't, it will prompt them to use the naming convention, but once entered, the program closes without continuing.

I want to change it so that it prompts them for the proper naming convention until it's entered correctly, then proceed to ask them for the alias (the alias requires no convention).

I've tried `do...while/until` but end up in a continuous loop, regardless of what gets entered. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
$name = Read-Host 'What is the SX20 name?'
if ($name -notlike "SX20VTC-[a-z , 0-9]*") {
    Read-Host 'Please begin naming conventions with "SX20VTC-".'
} else {
    $description = Read-Host 'What is the SX20 alias?'
    $content = (Get-Content C:\Users\SX20_Backup.txt) -replace 'NGMNVC-[a-z , 0-9]*', $name -replace 'SetDescriptionX', $description
    $filename = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$name.txt"
    [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($filename, $content)
}
```

Comment: Show us the `do...while/until` attempt

Comment: I was wondering when this issue would come up. Seen this code a few times today and this part didn't make sense.

Comment: I've been wondering what the expressions are actually supposed to match. You do realize that `-notlike` does wildcard matching whereas `-replace` does regular expression matching? And that `[a-z , 0-9]*` means different things in either context?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers `"SX20VTC-[a-z , 0-9]*"` is a perfectly good wildcard expression equivalent to `^SX20VTC-[a-z , 0-9]` with `regex`/`-match`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I didn't say it was invalid. However, they're not equivalent. A wildcard expression `[a-z , 0-9]*` matches one letter, comma, space or digit followed by any number of arbitrary characters. A regular expression `[a-z , 0-9]*` matches any number of the letters, commas, spaces or digits. At least one character vs. zero or more characters. Also, I have my doubts that the OP actually intended to match spaces or commas.

Comment: @Ansgar No, I did not realize they have different meanings in different context. I didn't even know what Powershell was a few days ago. This is something I've been putting together with help from Google and the users on this forum to streamline a process for my coworkers and I. It's very interesting, but I'm a novice at best

Comment: @Blake That doesn't answer the question what you *intend* to match with those expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing `if/else`. *Else* means *if not*. So if the use enters a name that is *not* following the naming convention, the `else` block never gets executed.

You want that part executed no matter what happens:

```
$name = Read-Host 'What is the SX20 name?'
if ($name -notlike "SX20VTC-[a-z , 0-9]*") {
    $name = Read-Host 'Please begin naming conventions with "SX20VTC-".'
}
$description = Read-Host 'What is the SX20 alias?'
$content = (Get-Content C:\Users\SX20_Backup.txt) -replace 'NGMNVC-[a-z , 0-9]*', $name -replace 'SetDescriptionX', $description
$filename = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$name.txt"
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($filename, $content)
```

---

With a `do{}until()` loop, you could keep asking for the `$name` value until they get it right:

```
do  {
    $name = Read-Host 'Please enter SX20 name, must start with "SX20VTC-".'
} until ($name -like "SX20VTC-[a-z , 0-9]*")
```

Comment: nelse? just askinjg;(

Comment: Thank you, Mathias. I had read somewhere that `do..until` wasn't used much and that `do..while` could essentially accomplish the same thing, so I was trying to use `$name = Read-Host 'What is the SX20 name?'
Do 
{(Read-Host 'Please begin naming conventions with "SX20VTC-".')

} While ($name -notlike "SX20VTC-[a-z , 0-9*]")` , which had me stuck in a loop until I closed the program.

Comment: @Blake To be clear, `do{}while($a -notlike $b)` is functionally the same as `do{}until($a -like $b)`, but for your usecase, I personally feel the `do{}until()` clearly reflects what you are trying to do, ie. better self-documentation